# How to turn off wavy red lines before code VS Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am getting the error wavy lines before each tab in VS Code.  Every google search points to error indicator below text, but my issue is before any code (tab spaces). I can delete space and add it back and it removes it for that one space.  The file is set for the correct language.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: do you use different types of whitespace to fill the line, enable `View Whitespace`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Enabling View->Render Whitespace adds the arrows for each tab.  It does not remove the wavy lines.

Comment: use an editor like `vi` or tool like `od` to view what characters are before the `<`. Because of UTF-8 they can be some tricky ones. What is the File Language?

Comment: You're correct, it was a character that VS code was detecting. I copied a 'blank' space, search and replace with a 'real' blank space.  Then I beautified my file.  Thanks!